# Windows Batch: How to parse an error message in the log and then execute a command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following error message in a error log and want to execute a restart of services if it's found.

java.io.UTFDataFormatException: Invalid UTF8 encoding.

Can someone help with writing the logic for this?

So #1, need logic to set a variable to this error message if found, then #2 rename the log (assuming it's test.log, rename to test_05162017.log) with timestamp, then lastly #3 write an IF statement, if it exists, restart service on \machine.

So far I have...

```
:Parse Log
@ECHO ON
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\tEST"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d /od "%sourcedir%\Test*.log" ') DO 
SET "filelog=%sourcedir%\%%a"
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=2 delims=:" %%a IN ("%filelog%") DO SET job=%%a

If "%job%" == " Invalid UTF8 encoding" (
    echo Found Error > err.log
) else (
    exit
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: (1) Why batch? (2) What have you tried?

Comment: I would prefer batch.

Comment: :Parse Log 
@ECHO ON 
SETLOCAL 
SET "sourcedir=C:\Oracle" 
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d /od "%sourcedir%\Planning1*.log" ') DO SET "filelog=%sourcedir%\%%a" 
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=2 delims=:" %%a IN ("%filelog%") DO SET job=%%a 

If "%job%" == " Invalid UTF8 encoding" ( 
 echo Found Error > err.log 
) else ( 
 exit 
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options here, both should output the path of any of your files containing a match to your err.log.

The first uses the built-in `findstr.exe`:

```bat
@FINDSTR/MILC:"Invalid UTF8 encoding" "C:\tEST\Test*.cmd">"Err.log"
@For %%A In ("Err.log") Do @If "%%~zA"=="0" @Del "%%A"
```

The second uses `find.exe` and is provided as an alternative and for potential errors with `findstr.exe` reading unicode files:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
>"Err.log" (FOR /F "TOKENS=* DELIMS=- " %%A IN (
    'FIND /I /C "Invalid UTF8 encoding" "C:\tEST\Test*.cmd"'
) DO FOR /F "TOKENS=1-3 DELIMS=:" %%B In ("%%A") DO IF %%D GTR 0 ECHO=%%B:%%C)
FOR %%A IN ("Err.log") DO IF "%%~zA"=="0" DEL "%%A"
```

*Note, the `find.exe` version as written works only for a full source file spec.*